# Difference between Facebook Connect and Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api

What is the difference between adding facebook connect to a website and connecting to facebook using its Graph API? I'm trying to create a facebook login functionality to extracts status information from a user facebook page- do I use the social Graph API or "Facebook Connect"?

Comment: you would need to use graph, facebook connect is more for the widgets/like buttons ect find all you need to know @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the javascript sdk for the graph api, although that would depend on the type of information you want to extract, also.
You can get the documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

and, to start, this will add a log in button and extract some basic information:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV id="fb-root"></div>
    <SCRIPT>
      FB.init({
        appId  : APP_ID, // You get this number when you register your app at http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        alert(" Welcome " + response.name);
      });
      if(FB.getSession() != null) {
        var session = FB.getSession();
        alert(" Your user id is " + session.uid);
      }
    </SCRIPT>
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink='true' show-faces='false' width='200' max-rows='1'></fb:login-button>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```